# Android binder - Limit binder calls to one process

Tags: android, android-binder

I have an Android Java service that interacts with a native process via binder (AIDL).

I see that the service gets listed under "adb shell service list". Also I can send commands to this service by using "adb shell service start 1 xxx".

To plug this, I would like the binder IPC transactions only between this particular Java service and the native process.

I couldn't find any conclusive info anywhere. Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this with SE Linux in enforcing or permissive mode? Check the output of getenforce. Usually, you would have to allow interaction between the services explicitly by means of SE Linux rules, so I would assume this is on a debug image with SE Linux running in permissive mode.

Answer (score 2):

Controlling the access of binder interfaces can be done with SELinux.

Depending on whether you are using `binder` or `vdbinder` you would define a service context in either a `service_contexts` or `vndservice_contexts` file like this:

```
myservice      u:object_r:myservice_[vnd]service:s0
```

**Note**: `myservice` is the name you provide in `defaultServiceManager()->addService()`

Now you can explicitly define which process is allowed to access `myservice` in a `.te` policy file.

**Example**: Allow `myclient` to access `myservice`:

```
allow myclient myservice_[vnd]service:service_manager find
[vnd]binder_use(myclient)
binder_call(myclient, myservice_[vnd]service)
```

You can fin more information [here](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl/binder-ipc#selinux).